# Preselect of value on input

Tags: javascript, html

I want ask you for help. I have form, where I change id by check-boxes:

```
<input id="SP_sid" type="hidden" name="sid" value="" /> 

<!--radio-->
<input name="sid_id" type="radio" value="1">One</input>
<input name="sid_id" type="radio" value="2">Two</input>

<!--script-->
<script>
jQuery('input[name="sid_id"]').click(function() {
    jQuery('#SP_sid').val(this.value);
});
</script>
```

but I need to have value of `sid` from beginning pre-set to "1".
If I put "1" to value of `sid`, I am not able to change it by script to "2".

Is there any easy solution to get it work like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
jQuery('input[name="sid_id"]').change(function() {
    jQuery('#SP_sid').val(jQuery(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, looks, that I get it work. I just change `jQuery('#SP_sid').val(jQuery(this).val());` to `jQuery('input[name="sid"]').val(jQuery(this).val());` I do not know why does not work with id, but with name I got it work.